# Can't run SSMS as another user - requires elevated permissions

Tags: windows-10, ssms

On Windows 10 and SSMS 2016, I can no longer start SSMS as another user. I need to be able to do this in order to use trusted authentication to connect to some of my databases. This used to work fine, but using Windows 7 and an older version of SSMS.

If I right-click on the icon and choose 'run as a different user', I now get this

[image]

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: If you click "restart under different credential", does it actually work ?

Comment: Is that a different option to "Run as a different user"? That's what I've been doing and I get the error above. A colleague who has the same setup (Windows 10) gets exactly the same problem too. Looks like a genuine bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3009405/ssms-2016-fails-on-windows-10-version-1607-while-trying-to-execute-it-as-a-different-domain-user

Comment: I think you found the corresponding bug report, as it's unresolved, you could post it as an answer, and downgrade your windows 10 from 1607's build as a workaround.

Comment: Yup, thanks for the advice. I've gone back to using the SSMS 2014 which still works fine on Windows 10 rather than downgrading Windows, but either would work (I expect).

Answer (score 9):

In case it helps anyone, I got it working by:

- Open the location to the shortcut, such as: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server Tools 17`
- Right-click > Properties > Compatibility >
- Select "Run this program as an administrator"
- Select the button "Change settings for all users" (THIS IS IMPORTANT)
- Again, select "Run this program as an administrator"
- Select "Okay", and 'Okay" again.

Hope it helps everyone.

Comment: Strangely enough, this works when the equivalent CMD.EXE commands do not. I.e. if I want to run SSMS.exe as another user, I should be able to use "RUNAS" and powershell to launch as Administrator for another user. However, this causes SSMS to crash - only this solution has worked so far.

Comment: Didn't work for me...Using SSMS v17.9, Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a known (unresolved) bug:

[Archived - SSMS 2016 fails on Windows 10 Version 1607 while trying to execute it as a different domain user](https://web.archive.org/web/20170908144326/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3009405/ssms-2016-fails-on-windows-10-version-1607-while-trying-to-execute-it-as-a-different-domain-user)

SSMS 2014 still works fine so that's a workaround, or as @yahmoth555 suggested, use a different build of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 with ssms2018 installed it is little bit tricky.

you need to reach out the application setup file(.exe) (not shortcut) of SSMS and then press SHIFT + Right Click.

Here you go! there you will see a option "run as different user "